# 'UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'. Trying to save and load a model

Tags: python

I have been stuck on this error for days.
I have created and saved a model on my Google Colab. It is saved in a '.tar' file. I want to save and load this model with the help of the torch library in Python. This is my code so far.

```
import torch
import pickle
import json

torch.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/model.tar',open('/content/drive/MyDrive/saved.tar', 'wb'))
filename = '/content/drive/MyDrive/saved.tar'

loaded =(torch.load(filename, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
```

'model.tar' is the tar file of the model I have on my colab which I need to load. I know that 'loaded' is now of type 'string', which means I am doing something wrong with my torch.save() function call. It would be great if anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: different versions of Python may use different methods to `pickle` data and later you can't read file created by other Python.

Comment: I see `save()` has option `pickle_protocol=...` and maybe this can help to read it. In both Pythosn you check `print(pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL)` and use lower value from both Pythons when you save file.

Comment: shouldn't be `torch.save(model, ...)`

Comment: I tried changing my pytorch version to the one I used to train the model. It says I cannot because it is not compatible with the other dependencies. Is there a way for me to change my pyTorch version to 1.11.0 from my Google Colab?

Comment: you will have to use different Torch to train model. OR you should find different file format to save model.